# Retrieve PEM-encoded private key from API Gateway Client Certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, encryption, certificate

I am following along with the following tutorial to add an SSL certificate to an API hosted with AWS API Gateway: [aws-docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html#generate-client-certificate). I am able to successfully follow along with Generate a client certificate using the API Gateway console, resulting in the following certificate:

[image: API Gateway Client Certificate]

I am also able to Configure API to use SSL certificates by following along the prompt. The issue comes in the section that is Configure a backend HTTPS server to verify the client certificate. The instructions specify that "you must have obtained the PEM-encoded private key and a server-side certificate". Pressing "copy" retrieves the certificate, but I never got a private key when creating the certificate, and I don't see any option to retrieve the private key. How would I go about retrieving the PEM-encoded private key for a certificate created using API Gateway?

The goal of all this is to create an http request using python's `requests` library. Without the certificate, when posting the request I get an error which looks like:

`(Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))`

You can specify a certificate and private key with requests like the following according to [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ssl-certificate-verification-python-requests/):

`result = requests.post(url, cert=('/path/client.cert', '/path/client.key')`

However, as stated above, there is no obvious way to get the PEM-encoded private key. Setting the flag `verify=False` for the `request` is not acceptable for this application due to security concerns. So either a way to get the PEM-encoded private key or create the python `request` in another way using just the .cert file obtained using the "copy" button would be acceptable solutions for this application.

Comment: You are confusing the API Gateway's certificate with the backed server's certificate. Each of them has their own private key and certificate. The Gateway's private key stays on the gateway. The server's private key stays on the server.

Comment: it's still to be a good question today.. What the propose of API Gateway client certificate is ? As aws gives us only a public key....

Answer (score 0):

I have recently faces the same issue, when I had to create a `Client Certificate`, as I was following the official [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html#generate-client-certificate).

I also didn't receive any `PEM` key

Therefore I resorted to using AWS CLI

```
aws apigateway  get-client-certificate  --client-certificate-id <<your_client_cert_id>>
```

[docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-client-certificate.html)